# Debug with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, awesomeprint

Up:
If it's true:

> "You wan to display a very complex object, you have a very complex
>   result."

How I could make easier the output?

---

I wanna pretty print @_controller and what I see:

1. `<%= debug @_controller %>`
   [image]

2.`<%= simple_format @_controller.to_yaml %>` 
error: "can't dump anonymous module: #"

3. `<%= @_controller.inspect %>`

[image]

4. `<%= raw ap(@_controller) %>`
   [image]

Is there are way to pretty print this object (@_controller)?

Like `echo '<pre>';print_r($object);echo '</pre>';` in php?

Thx a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by myself, its ok for me to print controller.methods and controller.instance_variables

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rails' `<%= a.inspect %>` is the "equivalent" of PHP' `print_r(a)`.

You wan to display a very complex object, you have a very complex result.

Comment: Thx you, is there some ways to get a short view of object?